# Is there a way to stop read-char from continuing after a specific character is read?

Tags: scheme

I was just wondering when taking a user input and you have gotten a certain character is there a way to stop read-char from reading the rest of the characters in the input.

The issue arises because this is in a loop and I need to only read the first character and move and prompt to a new input.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Your recent questions sound like you're trying to translate programming in some other language into Scheme. This usually doesn't end well.

Answer (score 0):

read-char will only read one char from a specific port. So the problem is in your programs control flow. Without any source code, it is not really possible to determine where that problem might be.

One way to read characters up to a certain character would be this:

```lisp
;; this function reads characters from port
;; until the character k is reached
;; all characters before k will be returned as one string
(define (read-until-k port)
  (let loop ((current-chr (read-char port))
             (output-string ""))
    (cond
      ((eof-object? current-chr) output-string)
      ((eq? current-chr #\k) output-string)
      (else
        (loop (read-char port)
              (string-append output-string 
                             (string current-chr)))))))
```